# read failed when passing inputstream to a different thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, httpurlconnection

I am attempting to write an `InputStream` to a `MultiPartEntity` but I keep hitting:

```
08-01 17:25:13.523    2737-2787/com.[project].[package].test E/Volley﹕ [12495] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://api.[project].com/
08-01 17:25:13.603    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
08-01 17:25:13.603    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:151)
08-01 17:25:13.603    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
08-01 17:25:13.604    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
08-01 17:25:13.605    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:482)
08-01 17:25:13.605    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:177)
08-01 17:25:13.605    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
08-01 17:25:13.605    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.InputStreamBody.writeTo(InputStreamBody.java:91)
08-01 17:25:13.605    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.doWriteTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:150)
08-01 17:25:13.606    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.entity.mime.AbstractMultipartForm.writeTo(AbstractMultipartForm.java:173)
08-01 17:25:13.606    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity.writeTo(MultipartFormEntity.java:97)
08-01 17:25:13.606    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RequestEntityProxy.writeTo(RequestEntityProxy.java:116)
08-01 17:25:13.606    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:155)
08-01 17:25:13.606    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.sendRequestEntity(CPoolProxy.java:149)
08-01 17:25:13.606    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:242)
08-01 17:25:13.607    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
08-01 17:25:13.607    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:260)
08-01 17:25:13.607    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
08-01 17:25:13.607    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
08-01 17:25:13.607    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:178)
08-01 17:25:13.607    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
08-01 17:25:13.607    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
08-01 17:25:13.608    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
08-01 17:25:13.608    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack.performRequest(HttpClientStack.java:87)
08-01 17:25:13.608    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:96)
08-01 17:25:13.608    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ ... 1 more
08-01 17:25:13.609    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
08-01 17:25:13.610    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.readBytes(Native Method)
08-01 17:25:13.610    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.read(Posix.java:165)
08-01 17:25:13.610    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.read(BlockGuardOs.java:230)
08-01 17:25:13.610    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:472)
08-01 17:25:13.610    2737-2737/com.[project].[package].test W/System.err﹕ ... 21 more
```

the stream is an `FileInputStream` returned from an `AssetFileDescriptor.createInputStream()`

Here I get the `AssetFileDescriptor`

```
AssetFileDescriptor file = getContext().getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(person,
                    "r");
```

then adding it to the multipart:

```
multipartRequest.addFileBody("file", file.createInputStream());
```

which is using the `MultipartEntityBuilder`:

```
public void addFileBody(String name, InputStream in){
    multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody(name, in);
}
```

I am using an `HttpURLConnection`
and am writing the body here:

*this (along with the entire connection) happens on a different thread*

```
private static void addBodyIfExists(HttpURLConnection connection, Request<?> request)
        throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
    if(request.getEntity() != null){
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.addRequestProperty(HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, request.getBodyContentType());
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        OutputStream out = connection.getOutputStream();
        request.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } else {
```

I tried googling it, however all I could find out was that it is most likely that the InputStream is closed, however I don't close it anywhere.

**EDIT:** seems the problem is that I am attempting to make the request from a seperate thread as this all works just fine when it happens on the same thread.

TL;DR:
Thread A gets filestream and creates request object, adds stream to object.
Thread B starts and takes said object, opens a connection, and attempts to read the stream/write to connection at which point the read error occurs.

Comment: You're closing `file` before sending the message.

Comment: @EJP "I tried googling it, however all I could find out was that it is most likely that the InputStream is closed, however I don't close it anywhere." after I call multipartRequest.addFileBody("file", file.createInputStream()); I don't do anything else with file, and I don't close the stream anywher

Comment: Nevertheless that's what the exception means. The file is closed. No two ways about it. The fact that there are two threads involved (why?) makes it more possible that the code doesn't behave the way you think.

Comment: @EJP thread B is a background thread that handles all network calls. And that's great that the file is closed, I figured that out before I posted the question, however that doesn't solve the problem, I need to know why. Furthermore, if it was that it gets closed somewhere, it makes no sense that it would work when everything happens on one thread, unless I have some misunderstanding about how both threads and streams work.

Answer (score 1):

[[ Turns out that s/he is reading an asset and sending it to the remote so this answer doesn't really help.  I'm going to leave it up as a placeholder for now. ]]

> System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)

As @EJP mentioned, this is trying to tell you that by the time the background thread goes to read from the stream, it has been closed.

Since this seems to be a web-client, I suspect you are trying to read a file from a GET or POST response and the response container has been shutdown and closed by the time the thread goes to read it.

There are a couple of ways to fix this:

- The thread making the request could read in the file itself and then pass the bytes in a buffer to the background thread for processing.
- The thread making the request could read in the file and save it in a temporary file on disk and then hand of the temp file name to the background thread.

But regardless, the thread handling the web-request has to complete the IO on the request before the web-request container is closed.

Comment: The stream comes from an `AssetFileDescriptor` [`createInputStream()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html#createInputStream()) and I can't find any reason that it should be closed, the only place I am closing it is on the other thread after I read it.

Comment: Huh "You own this descriptor and are responsible for closing it when done" says the javadocs.  It really seem like _someone_ is closing it.  Maybe put a breakpoint on InputStream.close() or something and see what pops up?